# Check if and only if array contains a specific object

Tags: php

I need to set `$use_paypal` to `TRUE` only if the `$products` array contains one or more objects with `term_id` property set to `36`.

This code works if `$products` contains one or more *36-items*, but it also sets `$use_paypal` to `TRUE` if `$products` contains other items.

```
$use_paypal = FALSE;
foreach ($products as $product) {
  // The values could be 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
  if ($product->term_id == 36) {
    $use_paypal = TRUE;
  }
}
return $use_paypal;
```

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: I only need to use PayPal if the item in your cart are all apparel. If you have accessories, apparel etc. then, it should return false,

Comment: add a bit of more code on your work to help you.

Comment: How the items in the cart looks like? is it an array?

Comment: Can you provide us with your `product` class?

Comment: Yes. It's an array. The values could be 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, I only need the 36, but if the values includes 30, 31 etc, then it should return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure all of your products have `apparel_id = 36` what I would do is set `$use_paypal` to true by default and if any of the products do not match, switch it to false. Take a look at this example:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($product->term_id != 36) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

To make you understand what happens.

- We set `$use_paypal` to `true`
- We loop through all products
- For each product we check if `$product->term_id` is not `36`
- If the `term_id` is not `36` we set `$use_paypal` to false

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one. Just a bit confused, what if the items in cart has values like this 30, 31, 36? Will it return to true?

Comment: No it will not. It will only return true if they are all 36

Comment: Well, your explanation above really makes sense. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You could improve the efficiency of this function by simply returning `false` inside the loop - there's no need to continue checking items once we know there is a mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cart items list is an array, like this,

```
$cart_items[] = $product (object);
$cart_items[] = $product (object);
```

you can use a function like below to do your work.

```
function isPaypal($cart_items){
    foreach( $cart_items as $product ){
        if ( $product->term_id != 36 ){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```